# Counter example of bounds on limit implies bounds on the sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Let $F_n(x)$ be a sequence of functions from **$[0, \infty]$** to [0,1], suppose $F_n(x)$ is monotone in x, and $F_n(x)$ converges uniformly to $F(x) = e^{-x}$. Find a counter example such that the following statement is not true:

$\exists N\in\mathbb{N}, \text{ s.t. } \forall n>N, \forall x, F_n(x)<e^{-\frac{x}{2}}$.

This is in analog to convergence of sequence:

$\{a_n\}\to a, |a|<\infty$, then $\forall b>a, \exists N\in\mathbb{N}, \text{s.t.} \forall n>N, a_n<b$.

Remark: an **non**  counter example is $F_n(x) = e^{-\frac{x}{1+\frac{1}{n}}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $F_n(x)=\frac {e^{-x}+\frac 1 n} {1+\frac 1 n }$. For large $x$ we don't have $F_n(x) <e^{-x/2}$.

Comment: +1 Sorry, did not see your nice example while typing.

Answer (score 1):

Take
$$ F_n(x) =  \begin{cases} 1,& 0\leq x \leq 1/n \\
e^{-x},& x\geq 2/n, \\
\end{cases} $$
and interpolate between the end points.